# Unable to match string literal '{*}' with regex by escaping \ for each special character

Tags: regex, python-3.x, special-characters

I am working with Python regular expressions and would like to create a regex to match the following string literal:

```
str = "JP 0.9300{*}%PEMULT% /"
```

The regex I am using is:

```
(^JP\s)(.+?)(\{\*\}%PEMULT%)(\s/$)
```

But the above regex does not seem to work for me and ends with an error saying:

```
 KeyError: '\\*\\'
```

I believe that it is due to the way I am trying to match special characters `'{*}'` with my regex.

Could anyone look at the regex and suggest how to format it in order to match the special characters  `'{*}'`

---

Updated with code and error below.

### Complete code:

```
import re


str = """
DATES                                  -- Generated : Petrel
  1 NOV 2017 /
  /

GEFAC                                  -- Generated : Petrel
  JP 0.9260{*}%PEMULT% /
  JI 0.9260{*}%PEMULT% /
  /
  """

date = "1\sNOV\s2017"
pe = "0.7000"


regex = r"""
(^DATES[^\d.]+?{0}.+?GEFAC.+?JP\s)                      #Group1 - String from DATES through JP\s
(.+?)                                                   #Group2 - JP PE
(\{\*\}%PEMULT%)                                        #Group3 - %PEMULT% Modifier
(.+?)                                                   #Group4
(JI\s)                                                  #Group5
(.+?)                                                   #Group6 - JI PE
(\{\*\}%PEMULT%)                                        #Group7 - %PEMULT% Modifier
 (\s/$)                                                 #Group8 - Trailing " /"
""".format(date)

p = re.compile(regex, re.DOTALL | re.VERBOSE | re.MULTILINE)
str = p.sub('\g<1>{0}\g<3>\g<4>\g<5>{1}\g<7>\g<8>'.format(pe, pe), str)

print (str)
```

### Error:

```
C:\appl\Python\3.2.1\python.exe I:/Private/nabm/python/regex/test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "I:/Private/nabm/python/regex/test.py", line 33, in <module>
    """.format(date)
KeyError: '\\*\\'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Show your Python code. I [cannot repro](https://ideone.com/lWfre1). Even with [a regex defined with a regular string literal](https://ideone.com/ZgG0w1).

Comment: See some info on [`KeyError`](https://wiki.python.org/moin/KeyError).

Comment: Did you try to use two backslashes? Sometimes you run into the problem that a language uses the backslash to escape characters in a string and you want the final resulting regex to include a backslash so you have to escape the backslash with a second backslash.

Comment: You don't have a regex issue here. You have a [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#custom-string-formatting) issue. (You might have a regex issue as well, and I suggest writing a structured parser instead of a very complex regex, but that's a different matter.)

Comment: Use `regex = r"{\*}"` instead of `regex = r"\{\*\}"`. Don't escape curly braces.

Comment: Could you show what output do you expect? I can get this: `JP 0.7000{*}%PEMULT%` but not sure it's what you're looking for.

Comment: `@zezollo  Yes, that is exactly the output I am looking for: `JP 0.7000{*}%PEMULT%`

Comment: @NabeelM. I posted how I did as an answer. I think it's what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`str.format()` uses braces to identify the parts of the string it should substitute. If the string contains braces, for example because it represents a regular expression, this can clash.

There are ways to resolve the clash by adding additional escaping to the braces (consult the documentation for `str.format()`) but this would make it much harder to see what is going on in the regex and impossible to test it in external tools like regex101.com.

In short, it's an all-round bad idea to use `str.format()` on regular expressions and recommend to avoid it altogether in this situation.

I also recommend not naming variables like built-in types. `str` should not be used as a variable name. I've renamed `date` to `date_expr` to signify that it does not contain a *date*, but a regular expression *matching* a date. For the same reason I made it a raw string.

```
import re

input_str = """
DATES                                  -- Generated : Petrel
  1 NOV 2017 /
  /

GEFAC                                  -- Generated : Petrel
  JP 0.9260{*}%PEMULT% /
  JI 0.9260{*}%PEMULT% /
  /
  """

date_expr = r"1\sNOV\s2017"
pe = "0.7000"


entry_expr = r"""
(^DATES[^\d.]+?""" + date_expr + """.+?GEFAC.+?JP\s)    #Group1 - String from DATES through JP\s
(.+?)                                                   #Group2 - JP PE
(\{\*\}%PEMULT%)                                        #Group3 - %PEMULT% Modifier
(.+?)                                                   #Group4
(JI\s)                                                  #Group5
(.+?)                                                   #Group6 - JI PE
(\{\*\}%PEMULT%)                                        #Group7 - %PEMULT% Modifier
 (\s/$)                                                 #Group8 - Trailing " /"
"""

p = re.compile(entry_expr, re.DOTALL | re.VERBOSE | re.MULTILINE)
result = p.sub('\g<1>{0}\g<3>\g<4>\g<5>{1}\g<7>\g<8>'.format(pe, pe), input_str)

print(result)
```

Using `str.format()` in the replacement string is okay in principle, but not super readable. Personally I would use `'\g<1>' + pe + '\g<3>\g<4>\g<5>' + pe + '\g<7>\g<8>'` instead.

Comment: If you are using `format`, you can make use of argument indexing and only provide `pe` once: `'\g<1>{0}\g<3>\g<4>\g<5>{0}\g<7>\g<8>'.format(pe)`.

Comment: @ChristianKönig I know, I thought about noting this as well. But in reality that's only a minor optimization of something I would not even be doing in the first place. String interpolation does not work well in the realm of regular expressions, it impairs the readability of expression while adding no actual value to the code.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is indeed with python's `str.format()` and the answer to escape braces in a string is [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax):

> If you need to include a brace character in the literal text, it can be escaped by doubling: {{ and }}.

So, in order to `format()` your regex correctly, you need to write `({{\*}}%PEMULT%)` instead of `(\{\*\}%PEMULT%)`.

Here is the modified script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import re


s = """
DATES                                  -- Generated : Petrel
  1 NOV 2017 /
  /

GEFAC                                  -- Generated : Petrel
  JP 0.9260{*}%PEMULT% /
  JI 0.9260{*}%PEMULT% /
  /
  """

date = "1\sNOV\s2017"
pe = "0.7000"


regex = r"""
(^DATES[^\d.]+?{0}.+?GEFAC.+?JP\s)                      #Group1 - String from DATES through JP\s
(.+?)                                                   #Group2 - JP PE
({{\*}}%PEMULT%)                                        #Group3 - %PEMULT% Modifier
(.+?)                                                   #Group4
(JI\s)                                                  #Group5
(.+?)                                                   #Group6 - JI PE
({{\*}}%PEMULT%)                                         #Group7 - %PEMULT% Modifier
 (\s/$)                                                 #Group8 - Trailing " /"
""".format(date)

p = re.compile(regex, re.DOTALL | re.VERBOSE | re.MULTILINE)
s = p.sub('\g<1>{0}\g<3>\g<4>\g<5>{1}\g<7>\g<8>'.format(pe, pe), s)
print(s)
```

And its output:

```
DATES                                  -- Generated : Petrel
  1 NOV 2017 /
  /

GEFAC                                  -- Generated : Petrel
  JP 0.7000{*}%PEMULT% /
  JI 0.7000{*}%PEMULT% /
  /
```

As a side note and as already written by Tomalak: take care not to use reserved keywords like `str` as variable names.